# How to make numbers the same length even though they have different values

Tags: java, math

So, i am creating a strategy game in java. Every one of the the dragons in the game have health, mana, and strength.

What I want to do is create 3 health bars for each of the 3 things listed above, that is simple but the problem is that I want them all to be 200 pixels long even though they may have different values.

For example, say 1 dragon has 192 health, 63 mana, and 38 strength. What kind of math would I use to make all the bars 200 pixels long?

Comment: Wow, you should provide us more information, add some code. The solution would be as simple as bar.setPixelSize(200) but we don't know how you're drawing the bars.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Should the health bar be number like text or some graphics like rectangle or something?

Comment: how you represent 192 health in 200 bar ?? red-8 and green-192 ? or what?what is the maximum possible health?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is just a normal proportion isn't it?

for dragon:

- health:   fillInPixels = 200 / 192 * currentDragonHealth
- mana:     fillInPixels = 200 / 63 * currentDragonMana
- strength: fillInPixels = 200 / 38 * currentDregonStrength

in general:

- fillInPixels = totalLengthInPixel / maxValue * currentValue